# Assign a random number (UUID) value to a environment variable in npm script

Tags: npm, uuid, npm-scripts

I'd like to add a UUID argument when calling my npm script. Each time the script is called, I'd like to generate a new number. It should look like:

```json
"build": "cross-env UUID=unique_number ng build"
```

The only thing I need is generating the `unique_number` here. I tried to use the uuid package but I don't know how to fire it in the script and pass the number as the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**tl;dr** As you're question shows the use of `cross-var` I've assumed a cross-platform solution is required. In which case refer to the **Solution A**. However refer to either **Solution B** or **C** if my assumption is incorrect.

---

### Solution A: Cross Platform (Windows/Linux/macOS...)

Fo a cross platform solution, (i.e. one that runs successfully on Windows, Linux, and macOS...), you'll need to utilize nodejs to achieve your requirement. There are a couple of different ways to approach this as described in the following two sub-sections titled:

- Using an external nodejs (.js) file
- Inlining your JavaScript in package.json.

<sub>**Note** both approaches are effectively the same</sub>

#### Using an external nodejs (.js) file

1. Create a nodejs utility script. Let's name the file *run-ng-build.js* and save it in the root of your project directory, i.e. in the same directory where *package.json* currently resides:

   ***run-ng-build.js***

   ```js
   const uuid = require('uuid/v1');
   const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;

   process.env.UUID = uuid();

   execSync('ng build', { stdio: [0, 1, 2]} );
   ```
2. In the `scripts` section of your *package.json* replace your current `build` script with the following:

   ***package.json***

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "build": "node run-ng-build"
   }
   ```

**Explanation:**

- In *run-ng-build.js* we require the [uuid](https://github.com/kelektiv/node-uuid) package and the nodejs built-in [`execSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options).
- To create the environment variable named `UUID` we utilize the nodejs builtin [`process.env`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_env), and assign a *uuid* value to it by invoking `uuid()`.
- We then invoke the `ng build` command using `execSync`.
- The [`options.stdio`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_options_stdio) option configures the pipes between the parent and child process - `[0, 1, 2]` effectively inherit's `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

#### Inlining your JavaScript in *package.json*.

Alternatively, you can inline your nodejs/JavaScript code in the `scripts` section of your *package.json*.

1. In the `scripts` section of your *package.json* replace your current `build` script with the following instead:

   ***package.json***

   ```json
   "scripts": {
     "build": "node -e \"process.env.UUID = require('uuid/v1')(); require('child_process').execSync('ng build', { stdio: [0, 1, 2]} );\""
   }
   ```

**Explanation:**

- This is effectively the same as the aforementioned solution that utilized a separate `.js` file, however the use of a separate nodejs script/file is now redundant.
- The nodejs command line option [`-e`](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_e_eval_script) is utilized to evaluate the inline JavaScript.

---

**Important** The [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) package is redundant utilizing either of the two aforementioned solutions. To uninstall it run: `npm un -D cross-env` via your CLI.

---

### Solution B: *Nix platforms only (Linux/MacOS...)

For *nix platforms only it becomes very terse, you can just define your `build` script in *package.json* as follows:

***package.json***

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "cross-env UUID=$(uuid) ng build"
}
```

This utilizes a Bash feature known as [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html), i.e. `$(uuid)`. However, if *nix is the only platform you need to support, then `cross-env` is really not necessary. Use the built-in [export](https://ss64.com/bash/export.html) feature instead. For instance:

***package.json***

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "export UUID=$(uuid) && ng build"
}
```

---

### Solution C: Windows only (cmd.exe)

On Windows (only) running via Command Prompt or PowerShell you can do the following:

***package.json***

```json
"scripts": {
  "build": "FOR /F %U IN ('uuid') DO cross-env UUID=%~U node -e \"process.env.UUID = require('uuid/v1')(); require('child_process').execSync('ng buuld', { stdio: [0, 1, 2] });\""
}
```

This is similar to the first example shown in *Solution B* however command substitution is achieved *(very)* differently in *cmd.exe*. See this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1020368/how-do-i-run-a-command-that-uses-the-result-of-a-nested-command-on-microsofts-w#answer-1020392) for further explanation.